# Error sending edittext in java server. See code

Tags: java, android, tcp, android-asynctask, port

Here is a working code of mine. But when I try to click the buttont that connects my client to port, my app crashes. See my code.

```
public class Order extends Activity {
    Button GoBackHome;
    private Button button1, button3;  
    private EditText txtbox1,txtbox2,txtbox3,txtbox4,textField;  
    private TextView tv;
    Button PayNow;
    CheckBox chxbx1, chxbx2, chxbx3,chxbx4;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.order);

            GoBackHome = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gohomebutton);
            PayNow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            txtbox1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText5);  
            txtbox2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
            txtbox3= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
            txtbox4= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
            chxbx1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
            chxbx2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
            chxbx3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
            chxbx4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkbox4);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
            textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
            button1.setOnClickListener(new clicker());
            Button get_view_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewsummary);
            get_view_button.setOnClickListener(get_view_button_listener);

            GoBackHome.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Intent i = new Intent(Order.this, MainActivity.class);               
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            PayNow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final Intent i = new Intent(Order.this, Payment.class);               
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

            chxbx1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (chxbx1.isChecked()) {
                        txtbox1.setEnabled(true);
                        txtbox1.setFocusable(true);
                    } else {
                        txtbox1.setEnabled(false);
                        txtbox1.setFocusable(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            chxbx2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (chxbx2.isChecked()) {
                        txtbox2.setEnabled(true);
                        txtbox2.setFocusable(true);
                    } else {
                        txtbox2.setEnabled(false);
                        txtbox2.setFocusable(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            chxbx3.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (chxbx3.isChecked()) {
                        txtbox3.setEnabled(true);
                        txtbox3.setFocusable(true);
                    } else {
                        txtbox3.setEnabled(false);
                        txtbox3.setFocusable(false);
                    }
                }
            });

            chxbx4.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                    if (chxbx4.isChecked()) {
                        txtbox4.setEnabled(true);
                        txtbox4.setFocusable(true);
                    } else {
                        txtbox4.setEnabled(false);
                        txtbox4.setFocusable(false);
                    }
                }
            });



    }

    private Button.OnClickListener get_view_button_listener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          String r = "";
          if (chxbx1.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx1.getText() + ".............." + txtbox1.getText().toString();
            txtbox1.setEnabled(true);
            txtbox1.setFocusable(true);
          }
          if (chxbx2.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx2.getText() + ".............." + txtbox2.getText().toString();
            txtbox2.setEnabled(true);
            txtbox2.setFocusable(true);
          }
          if (chxbx3.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx3.getText() + ".............." + txtbox3.getText().toString();
            txtbox3.setEnabled(true);
            txtbox3.setFocusable(true);
          }
          if (chxbx4.isChecked()) {
            r = r + "\n" + chxbx4.getText() + ".............." + txtbox4.getText().toString();
            txtbox4.setEnabled(true);
            txtbox4.setFocusable(true);
          }
          textField.setText(r);

          button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
          {

              public void onClick(View v)
              {
                  new ConnectToServerTask().execute(textField);
              }
          });

        }


      };



    class clicker implements Button.OnClickListener  
    {  
        public void onClick(View v)  
        {  
            String a,b,c,d;  
            Integer vis;  
            a = txtbox1.getText().toString();  
            b = txtbox2.getText().toString();
            c = txtbox3.getText().toString();
            d = txtbox4.getText().toString();
            vis = Integer.parseInt(a)*2+Integer.parseInt(b)*3+Integer.parseInt(c)*4+Integer.parseInt(d)*5;  
            tv.setText(vis.toString());  


        }  

    }  



}
```

I dont know if the positioning of the below code is on its right section.

```
button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
          {

              public void onClick(View v)
              {
                  new ConnectToServerTask().execute

(textField);
              }
          });
```

Here is my code on the server side:

public class TestTCP
{
    private static final int PORT = 1485;

```
private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
private static Socket clientSocket;
private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
private static String message;
private static String multiple;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT, 0, InetAddress.getLocalHost());

        System.out.println("IP:  " + serverSocket.getInetAddress() + "  Port:  " +  serverSocket.getLocalPort());

    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 1447");
    }

    System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 1447");

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {{
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client connection
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
            message = bufferedReader.readLine();

            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Message from Table 1: " + message);}
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();}

        } catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (bufferedReader != null)bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}}}
```

And this is for the Asynctask (If you want to see it):

```
public class ConnectToServerTask extends AsyncTask<View, Integer, Socket>
{
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.102";  // Kerv Server
    private static final int DEST_PORT = 1485; //port that is used

    private EditText mTextField;

    /**
     * Store provided views (used later in onPostExecute(...)).
     * 
     * Create socket to communicate with server (blocking call).
     */
    protected Socket doInBackground(View... params)
    {
        // Store provided views.
        if (params.length != 1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        mTextField = (EditText) params[0];


        // Create socket.
        Socket client = null;

        try
        {
            client = new Socket(IP_ADDRESS, DEST_PORT); // connect to server
        } catch (UnknownHostException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return client;
    }

    /**
     * Write to server.
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            PrintWriter printwriter;
            String messsage;

            messsage = mTextField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
            mTextField.setText("\n"); // Reset the text field to blank

            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();

            client.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at com.example.controlsystemfinale.ConnectToServerTask.onPostExecute(ConnectToServerTask.java:72)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at com.example.controlsystemfinale.ConnectToServerTask.onPostExecute(ConnectToServerTask.java:1)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:602)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:156)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:615)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-29 07:36:54.398: E/AndroidRuntime(31968):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Instead of all this code, a logcat output and only the most relevant section of code would be more helpful.

Comment: @codeMagic Logcat posted.

Comment: What is at line 72 of `ConnectToServerTask`?

Comment: I thinks its? messsage = mTextField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
            mTextField.setText("\n");

Comment: This one! printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);

Comment: If its the second one then you need to see why `client` is `null`

Comment: I'm having a trouble here. I cant get the error. What else do you need? Can you help me edit the code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is that `mTextField` is `null` in `ConnectToServerTask`. You either need to create a constructor in that class to accept an `EditText` which you are trying to pass it in your `onClick()` but it looks wrong or make it an inner class. If you are going to pass it then it should be like

```
new ConnectToServerTask(textField).execute;
```

then have a constructor to take an `EditText` like

```
public ConnectToServerTask(EditText textField)
{
    mTextField = textField;
}
```

which is going to cause you more problems. But if you make your `AsyncTask` an inner class of your `Activity` and `textField` is a member variable then your `AsyncTask` will already have access to it without passing anything.

**Edit**

```
public class Order extends Activity {
    Button GoBackHome;
    private Button button1, button3;  
    private EditText txtbox1,txtbox2,txtbox3,txtbox4,textField;  
    private TextView tv;
    Button PayNow;
    CheckBox chxbx1, chxbx2, chxbx3,chxbx4;


    // other functions such as onCreate()
    private class ConnectToServerTask extends AsyncTask<View, Integer, Socket> // inner class here inside your Activity
{
    private static final String IP_ADDRESS = "192.168.1.102";  // Kerv Server
    private static final int DEST_PORT = 1485; //port that is used

    private EditText mTextField;

    /**
    * Store provided views (used later in onPostExecute(...)).
    * 
    * Create socket to communicate with server (blocking call).
    */
    protected Socket doInBackground(View... params)
    {
```

Comment: I see. But I'm having really hard time here. What can I have done to make this better?

Comment: How can I make it as a inner class of my activity? like what you are saying?

Comment: Give me just a minute and I will give you a short example

Comment: @Kerv I have edited my answer with an abbreviated example of making it an inner class. You basically just place it somewhere inside of your `Activity`

Comment: I will insert it in my Order.java? Not in ConnectToServerTask.java?

Comment: .@codeMagic, I've added it on the last part of my activity but it said that this has no use at all. Please post the code. Pls?

Comment: Where are you calling it from?

Comment: At the very last part of my Order.java. Before the last two braces (}). Am i correct? I think not because its not functioning. What should I do? Can u please post the full code for just that innerclass in my Order.java? :) @codeMagic Please?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36426/discussion-between-codemagic-and-kerv)